# create two level headers before writing data on csv file (for better readability)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like create two level headers before writing the data in csv file (for better readability)

The first level should contain following headers: `model 1`, `model 2`, `model 3`.  Models would expand across two columns each (`estimates` and `observations`)

The second level should contain following header under each model: `estimates` and `observations`. I

The header `variables` can be in the first or the second level.

```
library(tidyverse)


tbl <- tibble(
  variables = c("a", "b", "c"), 
  
  `model 1_estimates` = c(1, 2, 3), 
  `model 1_observations` = c(10, 20, 30),
  
  `model 2_estimates` = c(4, 2, 3), 
  `model 2_observations` = c(40, 20, 300),
  
  `model 3_estimates` = c(4, 4, 3), 
  `model 3_observations` = c(40, 400, 300),
  
)
```

The output (in csv file) should look like this -

[image]

Comment: I'm fairly sure csvs don't have merged cells like your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.csv files don't have merged cells (this is because they are literally ***C***omma ***S***eparated ***V***alues, where each comma separated value is a value for a column)

Some alternatives you could try:

#### Tidy the data, and then store it in that form

Having the model number as part of the column name goes against [the principles of tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html). Tidy the data, then store it in that form:

```
tbl <- tbl %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -variables, names_to = c("model", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(model = as.numeric(sub("model ", "", model))) %>%
  arrange(model, variables, estimates)

# A tibble: 9 × 4
  variables model estimates observations
  <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
1 a             1         1           10
2 b             1         2           20
3 c             1         3           30
4 a             2         4           40
5 b             2         2           20
6 c             2         3          300
7 a             3         4           40
8 b             3         4          400
9 c             3         3          300

# then save this as a csv
```

#### Save as an Excel (.xlsx) file

```
#install.packages("openxlsx")
library(openxlsx)

tbl_new <- tbl %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
  add_row(variables = "", 
         `model 1_estimates` = "Estimates", `model 1_observations` = "Observations",
         `model 2_estimates` = "Estimates", `model 2_observations` = "Observations",
         `model 3_estimates` = "Estimates", `model 3_observations` = "Observations", 
         .before = 1) %>%
   add_row(variables = "variables",
            `model 1_estimates` = "model 1", `model 1_observations` = "model 1",
            `model 2_estimates` = "model 2", `model 2_observations` = "model 2",
            `model 3_estimates` = "model 3", `model 3_observations` = "model 3",
            .before = 1)
  
# turn tbl into a workbook
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")

writeData(wb, "Sheet1", tbl_new, colNames = FALSE)

# merge cells
mergeCells(wb, "Sheet1", cols = 2:3, rows = 1)
mergeCells(wb, "Sheet1", cols = 4:5, rows = 1)
mergeCells(wb, "Sheet1", cols = 6:7, rows = 1)

# centre text
addStyle(wb, "Sheet1", style = createStyle(halign = "center"), rows = 1, cols = 2:7)

openXL(wb)
```

[image]